# How do I set the jQuery framework in the new jsFiddle interface?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsfiddle

I must be missing something obvious, but how do I get jQuery to work in jsFiddle now?

The interface changed, it used to have a selection for framework and extensions.  I don't see that now.

I see examples that use jQuery, but have no reference that I can see.

I tried, but I get a $ is undefined error.  I'm assuming it's something simple that I am just failing to see...

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to click on `javascript` in its pane:

[image]

Comment: thanks, I knew it had to be simple, but a little help button might have been good if they were going to change the UI :)

Comment: Yes that's true, I've been including cdns for a month or so until I found it... @Brandon

Answer (score 1):

Click the gear icon in the top-right corner of the Javascript pane.  I feel your pain--it took me a while before I found it, too.  Another annoyance of the update is that the gear icon obscures code.